# Mood of subordinate clause after "sen"/"per"

Tags: prepositions, subordinate-clauses

Jen the following example sentences.

> Mi povas venki la <kion ajn>, sen tio, ke vi min {helpas,helpus,helpu}!
> Mi povas venki la <kion ajn>, per[e de] tio, ke vi min {helpas,helpus,helpu}!

I could very well have simply said "sen via helpo" or "per[e de] via helpo", or even reorder the clauses for clarity, but that would be besides the point of the question. Just wondering what moods the "helpi" can take when in a subordinate clause after a "sen tio" or "per tio".

Answer (score 1):

[PMEG 12.3.6.12](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/aliaj_rolvortetoj/sen.html) gives a general rule, that "*sen* estas la malo de *kun* kaj iafoje la malo de *per*". For *ke-frazoj* Wennergren adds "sed normale oni intermetas helpan tio" and gives an example

> *Via patro neniam povis ekrigardi vin **sen tio, ke li batus sin en la bruston kaj ĝemus*** [Rt40*]

(Your father can never look upon you without forging his chest and moaning. (my Google translation into English))

I think, that the logic goes the following way. Because *sen* means absence, lack i.e. the "tio" never happens, the subclause is imaginary i.e. use the *us-modo*.

Furthermore [PMEG 33.2.3](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/komplemento.html#i-knp) lists some cases, where you can leave the "tio" out before an explaining subclause. These are

- por ke
- malgraŭ ke
- anstataŭ ke
- krom ke
- sen ke

Note, that it is not wrong to use "tio" with these. So

- *Mi povas venki ion ajn sen (tio), ke vi min helpus*.

Based on my native language I prefer without, but you may prefer otherwise.

*: Rt40 = *La Rabistoj* de Friedrich Schiller tradukis de L. L. Zamenhof, p. 40

Comment: What about in the inverse case of "per", especially if the "tio" has yet to happen? Would this then still be in the conditional, for the reason you mentioned, or in the volitive this time? My guess is still us-modo, as the "tio" is not necessarily a celo, but instead something that *would* make the main clause realized.

Comment: I think, that Eduardo's answer covers the general case. I didn't found any "per ke" in Tekstaro and "per tio ke" only from 1991 onwards. At a glance they seem to be of "opinion type", i.e. _oni uzu la realan modon_ as Eduardo said.

Comment: I took a new look at the examples of use of _per tio ke_ in Tekstaro. Quite a many seems to correspond to the English "by that (it means/favours/implies/…"). Given that the Eo prepositions should usually be understood rather literally (e.g. _per_ should be used to denote a tool or a method), it seems more and more to me, that _per tio ke_ is mostly used in an erroneous fashion.

Answer (score 1):

Via demando estas tre detale respondita en PMEG ĉe [Verboformoj en ke-frazoj](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/ke/verboformoj.html). Vi trovos tie multajn ekzemplojn.

Resume:

- se la ĉeffrazo kaj la ke-frazo estas facile disigeblaj, oni uzu la saman verboformon

Laŭ la tipo de ke-frazo:

- cela: oni uzu la volan (-u) modon
- opinia: oni uzu realan modon (-is, as, -os). Tamen volan modon oni povas uzi se temas pri nerealaĵo.
- ebla: oni uzu realan modon -is, -as, -os).
- imaga: oni uzu imagan (-us) modon